# Specifying path to CSS files

Tags: html, css

This is such a basic question but I have struggled with this for a while now and can't seem to fix it.

I am trying to link to my css files from my index.html file, and get a 404 in the developer console.

My directory structure is as follows:
[image]

These are the errors:
[image]

And this is the relevant part of the index.html:
[image]

any help is really appreciated.

In addition the links are in my head tags.

Thanks

Comment: Why not `../css/normalize.css`?

Comment: Hi, have already tried this.

Comment: Have already tried ../css/normalize.css and ./css/normalize.css

Comment: I think this will help https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: What is your backend technology? It seems server does not configured properly to serve static files!

Comment: Hi dNitro, I'm using a mean stack. I'll look online about configuring it. I think you might be correct.

Comment: dNitro, you are a legend sir! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the comments. I hadn't configured my backend to serve static files in my css directory. Thank you so much for all the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated tmp folder for your application and you will find the right path to the css files.

I think that css it's not in the root folder and check that they are actually being copied by gulp.